# Usage of "since" and "from"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can anyone who knows the language well tell me if I should  use **since** or **from** in the following sentence?

Here is the example:

> I had a chronic liver disease **from/since** my childhood days. Now
>   I am fine after the operation.

Answer (score 1):

As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blind%20from%20birth%2Cblind%20since%20birth&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblind%20from%20birth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblind%20since%20birth%3B%2Cc0) charting relative prevalence of *blind **from/since** birth* shows, ***from*** has always been more common than ***since***...

[image]

But it's clear that both are in use, and ***since*** is steadily gaining traction. Personally, I would *prefer* to use the newer form, but this has nothing to do with possible differences in nuance (I don't think there are any), and it in no way implies there's anything wrong with using ***from***.

---

It may be worth pointing out that (for no particular reason that I can articulate), I'd be far more likely to say *...**since** I was a child/kid*. In which context I'll also note that to remain syntactically valid you'd have to replace ***since*** with ***from when*** there.

Also, people would often want to *emphasise* how long something has been the case, which is easily done with ***ever since***. You can't use ***ever*** with ***from*** like that - the best I can come up with is [***right from*** when I was...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22right%20from%20when%20I%20was%22), but that's vanishingly rare compared to [***ever since*** I was](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ever%20since%20I%20was%22).